# Running time complexity of the function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I need to find the running time complexity of this recursive function

```cpp
int f3(int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 10)
    {
        return i;
    }
    else if (i < 100)
    {
        return f3(i - 2, j);
    }
    else
    {
        return f3(i / 2, j);
    }
}
```

Is it O(logn) or O(n)? From my understanding since it divides the number by two growth rate of the number of calls with higher n is not linear but logarithmic. But the running time also depends on how big n is so I am not sure what is the correct answer.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Test it for various values of *n* in *10^n*. You'll very quickly find out the characteristics.

Comment: Seems odd that the function has a parameter `j`, but `j` is never used. Are you sure that code is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in that for large values of `i`, `i` gets halved at each recursive call. Each call also does only constant work. This is the important concept.

In big-O analysis, we only care about the growth rate of the function. It does not matter that for `i < 100`, the function takes "linear" time, as in the grand scheme of things, this is a constant amount of work for `i < 100`.

Another way to see this is that we can represent the running time of this algorithm with a recurrence.

For `i >= 100`, `i` gets halved and the function only does constant work. For `i < 100`, we can consider it as constant amount of work. So we have:

```
T(i) = O(1)             if i < 100
T(i) = T(i/2) + O(1)    otherwise
```

The solution to this is `O(log(i))`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at things a bit differently, here's a plot of something at least vaguely like your function:

[image]

Your plot is different from the plot for log(x) only at the far left side. But big-O really only cares about what it looks like at the far right side (and specifically, what it looks like on the far right when/if we stretch the right side out to infinity). And big-O only cares about the *shape* of the curve at the far right, not its vertical location or even its "orientation" (i.e., multiplying by a constant factor doesn't change it).

[Note that after the knee in the curve, this really is logarithmic, but by then x is large enough that log(x) is growing very slowly, so it looks almost like a straight horizontal line.]